# progressive enhancement on the server side?

Tags: javascript, server-side, progressive-enhancement

Currently many of the links on our pages get changed to `href="javascript:void(0);"` on pageload, but if you're impatient (as most users are) you can click the links before the page loads and land on the clunkier, non-javascript, non-ajax pages.

I'm thinking about progressive enhancement a lot these days, and I predict the majority of our users will have javascript enabled (no data yet, we havn't yet launched alpha)

**Is it a bad idea to generate some indicator that a user has javascript enabled for the session, and then serve pages that assume javascript? (ie. have the server put `href="javascript:void(0);"` from the start)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
<a href="oldversion.htm" onclick="...something useful......; return false;">link</a>
```

`return false` tells the browser not to carry on to the url in the href.

Now js visitors get fancy js, and non-js users fall back silently; and there is no need for changing links on pageload.

Comment: I was changing the href attribute with the jquery dom ready function! I HAVE BEEN REMISS ;) haha

Answer (score 0):

Do you do your progressive enhancement on load? You could try to move it to (a cross-browser version of) DOMReady.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you delegate this to the document, to keep your HTML clean?

For example, in jQuery:

```
$( document )
    .click( function(){ return false })
    .ready( function(){ $( this ).unbind( "click" ) } )
```